In Swift DateTimePicker how can i set 12 or 24 hour time format? based on my app settings not Device setting
i need to show time format in dateTimePicker is 12/24 hour time format based on my app settings not show based on device time format General-> time -> 12/24 hour, i try to change Locale also like
"
return timeFormat.isEqual("HH:mm") ? Locale(identifier: "en_GB") : Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
"
but its work in Gregorian calendar, when i set japanese calendar in device setting dateTimePicker  shows wrong year like doesn't show "Reiwa" prefix of the year. how to fix it, anyone face this problem


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let dateTextField = UITextField()
let datePickerContainer = UIView()
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
let toolbar = UIToolbar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupDateTextField()
    setupDatePickerContainer()
    setupToolbar()
    setupDatePicker()
}

func setupDateTextField() {
    dateTextField.placeholder = "Select date and time"
    dateTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    dateTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(dateTextField)
    
    // Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        dateTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        dateTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        dateTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        dateTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])
    
    dateTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDatePicker), for: .editingDidBegin)
}

func setupDatePickerContainer() {
    datePickerContainer.backgroundColor = .white
    datePickerContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    datePickerContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    datePickerContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    datePickerContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
    datePickerContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    datePickerContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(datePickerContainer)
    
    // Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        datePickerContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        datePickerContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        datePickerContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350),
        datePickerContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)
    ])
    
    datePickerContainer.isHidden = true
}

func setupDatePicker() {
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_POSIX") // Ensure 12-hour time format
    datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    datePickerContainer.addSubview(datePicker)
    
    // Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        datePicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        datePicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        datePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerContainer.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        datePicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.topAnchor, constant: -10)
    ])
}

func setupToolbar() {
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
    datePickerContainer.addSubview(toolbar)
    
    // Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerContainer.leadingAnchor),
        toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerContainer.trailingAnchor),
        toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerContainer.bottomAnchor),
        toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
    ])
}

@objc func showDatePicker() {
    view.endEditing(true)  // Dismiss the keyboard if any other input is active
    datePickerContainer.isHidden = false
}

@objc func dateChanged() {
    // Update the text field with the selected date and time based on user format
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = getUserPreferredDateFormat()
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
}

@objc func doneButtonTapped() {
    datePickerContainer.isHidden = true
    dateTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func getUserPreferredDateFormat() -> String {
    // Here you should implement how you get the user's preferred date format
    // For example purposes, let's assume the user wants "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    return "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
}

}

what's a DateTimePicker? Do you mean a DatePicker with a .datePickerStyle(.wheel)?

uploaded i tried swift code

your code does not seem to be related to the pictures you show. Can you show the code you have that produces the pictures.

Now you can check, code updated

Click that textField then calendar will be open and click month and year section top left corner of calendar. now will show the wheel of month and year now you can notice year is not contains "Reiwa" prefix only showing a number only thats my issue

You should build your own date picker.
